# Is there a difference between 'reform' and 'reformation'?

Tags: word-choice

According to the OED, 'reform' is defined as,

> [mass noun] the action or process of reforming an institution or practice.

The same definition appears in its entry for 'reformation'.

In terms of usage, is there any difference between the two words? Are they completely interchangeable, or is one preferable over the other?

Would 'Progressive reforms" mean the same as 'Progressive reformations'?

Comment: While synonymous, the word 'reformation' is often reserved to refer to specific historical periods and actions (i.e. *protestant reformation*); it's use to refer to contemporary changes is largely archaic/uncommon.

Comment: Looks like another [politically loaded question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116550/)

Comment: I might go slightly further than @LessPop_MoreFizz and say *the word 'reformation' is **usually** reserved to refer to specific historical periods and actions*, at least in British usage.

Comment: @TrevorD In American usage as well (at least in this American's experience).

Comment: @batpigandme Thanks. I didn't want to assume!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that reform is frequently used to refer to a specific change itself, whereas reformation is more often used to denote the set of changes made.

In the sentence above, "Would 'Progressive reforms" mean the same as 'Progressive reformations'?" the phrase 'progressive reforms' would be used to chronicle the specific changes, and would be more appropriate than the alternate phrase, 'progressive reformations.'